# adding <td> a specific place without having previous <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have table with one td at index 0

```
<table>
<tr class='xyz'>
<td> val1 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

now I want to add a td at index 1

```
$(".xyz").find("td").eq(0).after("<td>" +
"val2" +
"</td>");
```

so far it works perfect now due to some functionality I want to add td at 3rd index before I add one at 2nd index but the code below doesn't work as I don't have a td at 2nd index

```
$(".xyz").find("td").eq(2).after("<td>" +
"val4" +
"</td>");
```

any way around?

Comment: so you want to add an element as the 4th element, without having 3 elements but just 2 ? where would that td be in the html structure? suspended ? :) maybe i don't understand the question

Comment: why do you want it like that?

Comment: Could you please provide the HTML of the output you would expect from adding a "td at 3rd index before I add one at 2nd index"

Comment: Why not just do it after the second index and then the one you want to put in between, also put after the 2nd index when you need to

Comment: @MihaiT i want to have an empty space between index 3 and index 1 (again there is no td at index 2)

Comment: An index is defined by its position relative to other siblings.  Without a second index, it doesn't make sense to have a third index.  Not in HTML anyway.

Comment: @Profit actually I have random things coming all the time, so if i receive the value that needs to be on 3rd index before i receive the one that needs to be on 2nd index i have to add it at that very moment and not wait for the one that need to be on 2nd index

Comment: @Taplar that's what I am saying is there any way around? other than ".after" ".before" somehting like ".at"

Comment: No.  That's how HTML is defined.  If you want to have a third index, you have to have a second one.  Create an empty td for the second index, and make one for the third one, and fill in the third one.  Then when you get the second information in the future, don't create a new td, just fill in the second index td.

Comment: Otherwise you need to consider making a html structure that is not a true table, that you can manipulate in the way you desire.

Comment: why not add an empty td and populate it with value when you need to ? and after that empty td add your 4th td. Otherwise i can't think of a solution. You are basically adding html elements. in HTML you cannot add an element at position 4 without having position 3.

Comment: @Taplar thanks alot, i think those are the only two options u suggested, either have empty tds or html structure that is not a true table

Comment: @JunaidMasood this question is close to getting enough votes to be put on hold for being unclear - I voted to leave open, but 3/5 others didn't agree with me.  I believe that if you quickly edited the last part you would help the community understand what you want and keep the question open at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check expected result, use below option

1. Check if previous index td is available or not using length
2. Loop through index if not available and add empty td index to make it available
3. Add required val2 td

```js
function add(index){
  if($(".xyz").find("td").eq(index).length > 0){
     $(".xyz").find("td").eq(index).after("<td>" +
    "val2" +
    "</td>");    
  }else{
     for (i=0; i < index; ++i) {
      $(".xyz").find("td").eq(i).after("<td>" +
    "</td>"); 
   }
    $(".xyz").find("td").eq(index).after("<td>" +
    "val2" +
    "</td>");
  }
}


add(2);
```

```css
tr td{
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class='xyz'>
<td> val1 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vQgpYX

**Option 2:**

Use id for tds with index value and add elements after respective id using index

sample working code

```js
function add(i){
  $(".xyz td").each(function (index, value) {
  if(i > parseInt(value.id.split('td')[1])){
    if(i > parseInt($(".xyz td").last().attr('id').split('td')[1])){
      $(".xyz td").last().after("<td id=" +'td'+i+ ">" +
    "val" +i+
    "</td>");
      return false
    }else{
          $(this).after("<td id=" +'td'+i+ ">" +
    "val" +i+
    "</td>");
      return false
    }
  }else{
    if(i == parseInt(value.id.split('td')[1])){
       $(this).after("<td id=" +'td'+i+ ">"+
    "val" +i+
    "</td>");
        return false
    }
  }
  })  
  }


add(5);
//add(3);
//add(1);
//add(6)
```

```css
tr td{
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class='xyz'>
<td id="td0"> val0 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QJdaoP

Comment: thatks a lot, I had that in mind adding empty <td> but is there any way around other than ".after" ".before" somehting like ".at" because in my case I might receive the value of 999th index first and than 3rd index and the 2255 index, so i'll have to add a lot of empty tds :(

Comment: without having elements, after and before wont work and i think going with empty td to make it available next time

Comment: @JunaidMasood, uncomment those add methods to add tds before and after based on index

Comment: option 2 adds empty tds, one of solutions, thanks :)
though I will use alternate option but i,ll make it answer

Answer (score 0):

Create a little helper function that will either use `after()` or `append()` depending on what already exists

Something like:

```js
function addCell($row, index, val){
    var $newCell = $('<td>').html(val),
        $cells=$row.children();
        
    // if cell at index exists inster after the existing cell     
    if($cells.eq(index).length){
        $cells.eq(index).after($newCell)        
    }else{
     // otherwise just append to the row   
        $row.append($newCell)
    }
}

var $row = $('.xyz')
addCell($row, 1, "first")
addCell($row, 1, "second")
addCell($row, 1, "third")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class='xyz'>
<td> val1 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You might need some looping conditionals, in the case that they try to jump straight from one td to 4th td.

Comment: @Taplar right, not sure if OP wants to fill up to that index

Comment: thatks a lot, is there any way around other than ".after" ".before" something like ".at" because in my case I might receive the value of 999th index first and than 3rd index and the 2255 index, so append won't work :(

Comment: @JunaidMasood is there any way you would know at the beginning how many cells each row should have?

Comment: @charlietfl yes I have requested to update the API I am receiving to let me know the no of cells i will have
that is the best solution
i hope other side of code will be updated in few days
thanks for suggestion, means much

Comment: Agree. Better to just start with full table and then no inserting required, just update content at each index